# systemd service not starting using dbus interface

Tags: dbus, systemd

I am trying to start systemd service usnig dbus service. I am following the example 5 of below mentioned link:
http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

My dbus service is:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=com.native.Test_Dbus_060
Exec=/usr/sbin/server_060
User=apps
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/ttyS0
SystemdService=com.native.Test_Dbus_060.service
```

my systemd com.native.Test_Dbus_060.service is:

```
[Unit]
Description=dbus test server

[Service]
Type=dbus
BusName=com.native.Test_Dbus_060
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/server_060
StandardOutput=tty
TTYPath=/dev/ttyS0

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now when I am trying to activate `com.native.Test_Dbus_060.service` service by acquiring the above mentioned bus in dbus, its not starting.
Both server_060 and client_060 are using dbus APIs for IPC.

NOTE: my server_060 and client_060 are communicating fine when using directly without systemd service and dbus service.

Here my first query is, whether such type of systemd service start possible?
and if yes then why it is not working in my case?

Comment: Have you looked at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User#D-Bus ?

Comment: Did you solve this? I'm having similar problems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as the systemd tag states: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com. Please delete this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a closer look at the page you referenced you'll notice this note:

> For bus-activatable services, don't include a "[Install]" section in the systemd service file, but use the SystemdService= option in the corresponding DBus service file, for example (/usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.example.simple-dbus-service.service)